How to make annotations follow the latitude lines in QGIS?
If my map is in EPSG:4326, the text annotation is normal.

However, if the projection is transformed, such as EPSG:102017, the text label does not change.

I want the text label information to be labeled in the direction of the latitude, like in the image below. What should I do?
This

gis.stackexchange.com/a/440371/88814

method can curve the annotation information, but the upper part is still not truly rotated.



It doesn't follow the direction of the weft strictly, the top half still follows the reader's point of view, and doesn't really rotate


Follow the instruction in this solution.

To rotate the labels in the upper part to be upside down, in the label settings got to the tab Rendering -> Show upside-down labels and check the box always.



